# Undefined Control Sequence?

Tags: errors

I have a problem while practicing latex here.
Actually, I am newbie in using this application.

I found [image]

Where my code is here : [image]

Does anyone know what the matter here ? And what should I do to make it fix ?

Regards,
CP

Comment: The command for the \LaTeX logo is `\LaTeX`, not `\Latex`.

Comment: `\maketitle` is after `\begin{document}`

Comment: Besides what Bernard said, you need an explicit space `\LaTeX\ Document`; othersise, Document will appear with no space after the logo.

Comment: Hi @Bernard, I have revised as you advised but it keeps wrong.

Comment: Hi Juanuni, I changed the order and it stays wrong.

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, I added another '\' after LaTex but it stays wrong.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example illustrating the problem (fully compilable)?

Comment: Can you recheck the case of the letters `L`, `T` and `X` in `\LaTeX`? Those three letters all have to be upper case.

Comment: a minimal example is needed : `\documentclass{..}......\begin{document}..\end{document}`

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{Christin Panjaitan}
\title{My Practise \LaTeX\ Document} % <-- use \LaTeX, not \Latex 

\begin{document}
\maketitle % <-- comes after \begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet.  
\end{document}
```